# Download a canvas as PNG image

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, download, png

When i try to download my canvas as PNG image the browser open the image in a new page but don't download it...
my code for download :

```
$("#btnScaricaEtichetta").click(function(){
    console.log("Download... ");

    location.href = document.getElementById("latoSinistro").toDataURL();
    this.download = "filename";
});
```

there is a way to simply download it?
sorry for bad english, i'm italian

Comment: `canvas.toDataURL("image/png")` ?  Are you sure `location.href` is correctly grabbing the canvas?  Also look at `image/png` argument.

Comment: i have add "image/png" to toDataURL function but the results don't change.... the browser open a window and show the img with this url : data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoA ecc ecc (so long)

Comment: In the line `this.download = "filename";`  Its not clear what `this` is pointing to.

Comment: Check out [the answers at this link.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11112321/how-to-save-canvas-as-png-image?rq=1)

Comment: It's not location's but the anchor's href you want to change (probably "this") also you may be better set the download attribute first, and I'm not sure setting it on the fly like this will work everywhere.

Comment: @alex Let me build up a jsfiddle (hint. way easier if you did this.)

Comment: Frick. `document.write is disallowed in JSFiddle environment and might break your fiddle.`  Aaaargh!

Comment: ok @zipzit thanks a lot (:

Comment: I just have to save the image , how can it be so complicated? :(

Comment: A couple of thoughts: (1) In Chrome & FF you can `right-click-save` the canvas as an image. (2) In IE, the anchor download attribute is not supported.

Comment: i need to download by button because this project is for school. i have a node.js server, con it helps?

Comment: Check out [this link, and the answer by Tomas Zato](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23223718/failed-to-execute-btoa-on-window-the-string-to-be-encoded-contains-characte) I've seen a few other sites where they've used `fileSaver.js` as well.  The issue, of course, is finding a solution that works on the largest number of current browsers.

Comment: @markE, to be fair, Edge does support the `download` attribute, but Safari still doesn't. Also, IE>10 have a `navigator.msSaveBlob` method.

Comment: @Kaiido ... just thoughts ... these are just thoughts. :-P

Comment: @Kaiido. Agreed. This question has already been asked and well answered. :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because it uses external functions, this is sort of a hack, but it does seem to work on any browser.  I'm using the tool FileSaver.js to do the file download work, and canvas-toBlob.js to perform the toBlob functioning on Chrome and other browsers.

```
<script src="https://rawgit.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/master/FileSaver.js"></script>
<script src ="https://rawgit.com/eligrey/canvas-toBlob.js/master/canvas-toBlob.js"></script>

<h1 onclick="download_image()">Click Here to download image</h1>
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="200" height="100" style="border:1px solid #000000;">

<script>
  // lets put something on a canvas.. 
  // reminder this works without jQuery .ready() only because this script is the last element in the document.
    var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
    ctx.fillStyle = "#FF0000";
    ctx.fillRect(0,0,150,75);
    ctx.moveTo(0,0);
    ctx.lineTo(200,100);
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(95,50,40,0,2*Math.PI);
    ctx.stroke();

    function download_image(){
        // Dump the canvas contents to a file.
        var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
        canvas.toBlob(function(blob) {
            saveAs(blob, "output.png");
        }, "image/png");
    };
</script>
```

Comment: works, thanks a lot man (: